# How to update this deprecated React.PropTypes code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Below is the current error I'm getting:

[image]

Here is my current PropTypes code, I need to check if the objects inside of the Array coming in have the following properties (`id` and `name`).

```
React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
    React.PropTypes.shape({
        id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
).isRequired
```

Reading here https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/463 apparently `React.PropTypes` is going to be deprecated.

However how would you check the types inside of an Object that is in an Array coming in via the Props with just this logic:

```
AssetsTable.propTypes = {
    asset: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    price_usd: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Basically, the Array coming in, has objects which look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) supports shape just like `React.PropTypes`

From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes):

```
  // An object taking on a particular shape
  optionalObjectWithShape: PropTypes.shape({
    color: PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: PropTypes.number
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up with this, `arrayWithShape` : `AssetsTable.propTypes = {
   arrayWithShape: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
   }))
}`

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using `React.PropTypes`, first you need to install the `prop-types` package (trough npm or your favourite package manager). Then import it with `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`, and then use `PropTypes` just as you would `React.PropTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proptypes) library the same as you would with React.
e.g.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   static propTypes = {
      someValue: PropTypes.number
   }
}
```